# video cannot play after upload from retrofit to wcf

Tags: c#, android, wcf, upload, retrofit

I want to upload a video by retrofit to WCF Service. I can upload video as well and I can save this video in a specific path on the server.
But, unfortunately, this video cannot play after storing on the server by any media player. I try these codes both of "WCF" and "Android Java" like below:

**In Android:**

```
@Multipart
    @POST("MYSERVER/UploadVideo/")
    @Headers({
            "Content-Type: multipart/form-data",
            "Accept: application/json;charset=utf-8"
    })
    Call<Verify> uploadVideo(
            @Part MultipartBody.Part images

    );

 RequestBody requestFile =
RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);

fileBody =
  MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("videoData", file.getName(), requestFile);

Call<Verify> call = service.uploadVideo(fileBody);
```

**In WCF Service:**

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", UriTemplate = "/UploadVideo/",
RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        VerifyModel UploadVideo(Stream video);




 string apPath = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath + "Uploads\\Videos\\" + videoname;



using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(apPath, FileMode.CreateNew, FileAccess.Write))
{
   CopyStream(video, fs);
 }

public static void CopyStream(Stream input, Stream output)
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[8 * 1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = input.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                output.Write(buffer, 0, len);
            }
        }
```

as I told you, I can save the video with the correct size and mp4 format. but the video cannot play with any media player

[image: Video Cannot play]

Answer (score 0):

```
 I hope this will helpful for you. Retrofit with rxJava


 @Headers({
        "Accept: application/json"
 })
  @Multipart
  @POST("/api/uploadfiles")
   Observable<UploadFileModel> uploadData(@Header("Authorization") String 
   headerKey, @Part("destFolderPath") RequestBody destFolderPath, @Part 
    MultipartBody.Part file);




/**
 *  
 * @param fileName Name of Uploaded File here
 * @param mineType MineType of uploaded File
 * @param byteArray i convert the uri to byte array by InputStream  you can use 
  file also
 */


public void getData(String fileName,String mineType , byte byteArray[]) {

    //
    Log.e("File Name", fileName);
    Log.e("MineType", mineType);



      String path = ""; // this is destination folder path where i want to upload the file
    RequestBody description = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, path);


    String file_Name = fileName;

    // create RequestBody instance from file
    RequestBody requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("*/*"), byteArray);
    // MultipartBody.Part is used to send also the actual file name

    MultipartBody.Part fileToUpload = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file_Name, requestBody);


    AppController appController = AppController.create(mContext);
    ApiInterface apiInterface = appController.getUserService();

    Disposable disposable = apiInterface.uploadData(sharedPreferences.getString(TOEKNTYPE, "") + " " + sharedPreferences.getString(ACCESS_TOKEN, ""), description, fileToUpload)
            .subscribeOn(appController.subscribeScheduler())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Consumer<UploadFileModel>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(UploadFileModel uploadFileModel) {
                    loading.set(GONE);

                }
            }, new Consumer<Throwable>() {
                @Override
                public void accept(Throwable throwable) {

                    loading.set(GONE);
                    getActivity(mContext).getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE);

                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Something wents wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


                }
            });

    compositeDisposable.add(disposable);


}
```